# How to List all names in Dropdown list when I focus or mouse click or onClick in the EditableComboBox field

Tags: java, swing, listener, jcombobox

I have one "Name" EditableComboBox field, I have to display all the names in dropdown list in the name field when I focus or mouse click or onClick in the EditableComboBox field .How will i implement this using listener and which listener should i use for this? EdiatableComboBox contains JComboBox and JTextField.

screenshot of Name field.

[image: Name Field]

Comment: How to display all the list in dropdown using FocusListener?

Answer (score 1):

In the FocusListener you can use:

```
comboBox.setPopupVisible( true );
```

First try adding the `FocusListener` to the `JComboBox`.

Or if you are using an editable combo box you many need to add the listener to the editor of the combo box:

```
comboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addFocusListener(...);
```